# How to make the button inline with search bar?

Tags: html

I want to make the search bar full width on my site, but once I put style="width:100%", the button dropped to next line. I tried to add float:right display:inline to button but it won't work and the button will lost function.

```
<div class="ny-search-input">
    <form id="ny-search-form" action="https://pubject.com/project/">
      <input style="width:100%" placeholder="Search Projects.." type="search" name="s" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="">
      <button><i class="search_link icon-search-light"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Example:
[image: Sample image:]

Comment: Please add the css as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox to achive this

```
form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
input {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

The `flex: 1 1 auto` will make the input fully flexible so input will absorb any extra space along the main axis.

You should also remove the `width: 100%` from `input` tag

```
<input placeholder="Search Projects.." type="search" name="s" value="">
```